# Add r_liteprofile permission on LinkedIn Dev app OAuth 2.0 #linkedin

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

As part of our integration on our ATS, Avature, we're having an error when setting up the Share to functionality. We have set up LinkedIn Dev apps to progress, though Avature has advised we need the r_liteprofile permission added. This wasn't/isn't an option to select when creating the apps or to add later on. They have referred us back to LI to help.

How can we add this in?

[image]

By creating app, was expecting to have r_liteprofile permission